# How is the usages of FastClick for dynamic build element?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery in my web page. Adding FastClick.js in `<script>` tag for iPad & mobile browser. And attached it on document ready handler for body like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){                       
     FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

Some interaction I am creating elements dynamically with click events.

Is 'fastclick' will work for newly created element?

Comment: Yes. The FastClick is working for dynamic build element. Tested in iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The FastClick is working for dynamic build element. 
Tested in iPad.